Query any/specific using single/multiple values without using if blocks
I've finally managed to get my filter to work properly, however I am using a bunch of if/else statements, can this code be simplified, can the conditions be parts of the actual queries?
category is a string and difficulty is an array, searchTerm is not important
if (category && difficulty) {
        recipes = await Recipe.find({
            ...searchTerm,
            difficulty: { $in: difficulty.split(",") },
        })
            .where("category")
            .equals(category);
    } else if (category) {
        recipes = await Recipe.find({ ...searchTerm })
            .where("category")
            .equals(category);
    } else if (difficulty) {
        recipes = await Recipe.find({
            ...searchTerm,
            difficulty: { $in: difficulty.split(",") },
        });
    } else {
        recipes = await Recipe.find({ ...searchTerm });
    }


https://mongoplayground.net/p/VeIKwifJJ06 did you try this

@cmgchess no buddy, even if it works I don't get it and it's just too much.

it uses aggregation framework. the vars i have given the inputs. in the query im doing an $and query. im checking if the given var is empty. if not empty the $in is applied otherwise empty query. unfortunately youll have to write huge mongo queries if you dont want to build the query on server side

What do you mean by server side? I am building the query on the server side using express, based on more or less this request: /api/recipes?searchTerm=&category=6630ed7d4173ee9c904f3ecb&difficulty=medium%2Ceasy

yeah from server side i meant exactly what you have done right now with the if statements.

maybe in your server side code you can do some improvements. instead of having Recipe.find in each branch in if statement. just build the query dynamically and then finally pass into a Recipe.find(query)

@cmgchess I don't know how to do that, I guess I'd figure it out using just the object passed to Find but wouldn't know what to do with where equals

You can build the query before providing it to the .find() query as below:
if (category) {
    searchTerm = {
        ...searchTerm,
        category: category
    }
}

if (difficulty) {
    searchTerm = {
        ...searchTerm,
        difficulty: { $in: difficulty.split(",") }
    }
}

recipes = await Recipe.find(searchTerm);

Besedies, you can chain the .where() with multiple (filter) conditions and execute the query when it is ready.
let query = Recipe.find(searchTerm);

if (category) {
    query = query.where("category")
        .equals(category);
}

if (difficulty) {
    query = query.where("difficulty")
        .in(difficulty.split(","));
}

recipes = await query.exec();

